# Real part of the 2D Fourier Transform with alternative positive and negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fft

I have alternative positive and negative values in my 2D Fourier Transform, i'm in the case where my image is centro-symmetric (checked looking the imaginary part which is equal to zero) and all the values are positive.

I don't understand why I have those alternative positive and negative values in the real part of the FFT, I remarked also that I have the same problem with the imaginary part when my image is not centro-symmetric (not the case here for this simple and short example) :

**Image**

[image]

**Real Part of the FFT zoomed in**

[image: Real Part of the FFT zoomed in]

**Real Part of the FFT**

[image: Real Part of the FFT]

**Modulus of the Real Part**

[image: Modulus of the Real Part of the FFT]

Here is the code able to reproduce this work and my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2, fftshift, ifftshift

def imaging_model(rho,I_profile, R_image, **kwargs):
    
    method        = kwargs.get('method', 'linear')    

    
    # image_TOT = []
    xv = np.linspace(-R_image, R_image, len(rho)*2, endpoint=False) # Taille de la fenetre
    # WARNING
    if np.sqrt(R_image**2+R_image**2)>=max(rho):
        print('WARNING points out of the computation range are needed to display the image, they are set to 0')
    interpol_index = interp1d(rho, I_profile,kind=method)    
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xv, xv)
    profilegrid2 = np.zeros(X.shape, float)
    current_radius = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    cond=np.logical_and(current_radius<=max(rho),current_radius>=min(rho)) # Min et max des données
    profilegrid2[cond] = interpol_index(current_radius[cond])    

    # image_TOT.append(profilegrid2)             

    # plt.figure()
    # plt.imshow(profilegrid2,extent=[-R_image,R_image,-R_image,R_image])
    # plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$ [mas]')
    # plt.ylabel(r'$\delta$ [mas]')
    # plt.colorbar(label=r'Intensity Ratio [I_tot/I_star]')
    # plt.title('Image of the model at %.2f µm'%wavel_UD)    
    return xv, profilegrid2  

def FFT(image):
    
    FFT_image = fftshift(fft2(image))

    return FFT_image

test_x = np.linspace(0,270,256)
test_y = np.ones(256)
test_y[test_x>10] = 0

image_test_x, image_test  = imaging_model(test_x, test_y, max(test_x))

FFT_image = FFT(image_test)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_test)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.real(FFT_image))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.abs(np.real(FFT_image)))


plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.imag(FFT_image))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the FFT definition :

```
def FFT(image):
    
    FFT_image = fftshift(fft2(image))

    return FFT_image
```

The corrected one is :

```
def FFT(image):
    
    FFT_image = ifftshift((fft2(fftshift(image))))

    return FFT_image
```